# I need a user to browse directory to select a location to save a file in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code that will use the path and download the file. It would be great if the user could browse their local directory and it would return the selected path as a string to my application.

Comment: Why would you want this? Your web app shouldn't know, nor even care, about the users local directory structure.

Comment: Our application produces reports for the user using the reportviewer component.  They usually need to save these and we would like for them to be able to choose the storage location on the fly.

Comment: But your web app *cannot* choose where downloaded files will go, that's impossible.

Comment: In my current code I have the application programmed to save a pdf or excel file to a location on c: in a test folder and it does work after I have granted folder access to iis.

Comment: So you're assuming the web app is running on IIS on the users machine, and not on a server?

Comment: The web application is running on our server at the moment and I performed the test on my personal computer at home.  Let me find out from my team if we will be placing this application on our clients machines or running just from our server.  I'll be back.

Comment: I'm going to assume it is running on our server.

Comment: So, like I said, you absolutely cannot choose a folder on the remote users computer - the browser doesn't have that access. This is by design too.

Comment: There is no way to produce a save as dialog allowing them to select the location to save to at all?

Comment: Most browsers will just download a file to the default location these days, you can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Actually you even can't rely on a fact that user will have "folders". For example on iOS browsers don't expose them to the user and they (browsers) just provide some different means to handle downloaded files in other applications.

The best you can do is to return your file in response and add a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to suggest to the browser that this is a file to download. Then it is up to the browser how to handle it. Depending on specific browser, OS and configuration browser might save the file to prefered user's location, ask the user to select location to download file, reject it, or do something else.

If your are using ASP.NET MVC, [`FileResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx) class and its subclasses might be useful. Also take a look at various `File` methods in the [`Controller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.118).aspx) class